# How many samples does one need to perform polynomial regression of degree $m$?

Tags: regression, estimators, asymptotics, polynomial

Suppose $(X_i, Y_i)$, $i = 1,\dots, n$ are random variables such that
$$X_i\sim N(0,1)$$
$$Y_i = f(X_i) + \epsilon_i$$
where the $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussian and $f(x)=\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \beta_k x^k$ is an analytic function. For each $n$ and $m < n$, one can perform a multivariate linear regression over polynomials of degree $m$ by minimizing
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n\Big(Y_i - \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \beta_k X_i^k \Big)^2$$
over $(\beta_0,\dots, \beta_m)\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and get a polynomial estimator $\hat{p}^{(m)}(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \hat{\beta_k} x^k.$

I am curious what is known about the behavior of, say, $\mathbb{E}[|f(Z)-\hat{p}^{(m)}(Z)|^2]$ where $Z$ is an independent Gaussian as $m,n\to \infty$. (Or some other metric of average distance between $f$ and the estimator and $\hat{p}^{(m)}$.)

When $m=n-1$ I would expect the estimation to break down because of noise. But, as $n\to \infty$ with $m$ fixed, I would expect to get some limiting best fit polynomial of degree $m$ to $f$. If we want to $m\to \infty$ can one find an explicit sequence $n = n(m)$ (in terms of, say, some generic property about the function $f$) so that the error goes to zero?

In other words, how many samples should one have in order to succesfully do polynomial regression up to degree $m$? What happens if instead of using the basis $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ one takes some other basis $\{\phi_0,\phi_1,\dots\}$ for continuous functions $\phi_i$?

Comment: Do you assume that $f$ is correctly specified (i.e. infinite-dimensional polynomial of $x$ plus a Gaussian noise)?

Comment: If I understand what you mean then yes, the $Y_i$ are defined to be equal to $f(X_i)$ plus Gaussian noise. Really what I wanted to represent was some non-linear relationship that isn’t too crazy.